# Unable to perform DNS queries over IPv6 from laptop

Tags: dns, ipv6

I was trying to perform a DNS query over IPv6 from my laptop using `dig`, and it didn't work. Here are the details:

`ping6 google.com` works fine

`dig -6 google.com` times out due to being unable to reach any servers

`dig -6 @fd85:x:x::1 google.com` works fine

`dig -6 @2601:y:y:y::1 google.com` also works fine

The last two requests are being made directly to my router where I am running dnsmasq.

I couldn't figure out how to see what DNS servers are being sent to my laptop over DHCPv6, but on my phone it lists these three (set automatically):

```
192.168.1.1
fd85:x:x::1
2601:y:y:y::1
```

The reason why I am asking on this forum is because it appears to be a problem only for my laptop, since my phone correctly sees the DNSv6 servers.
I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and my network settings show the IPv6 method and DNS as 'automatic'.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, this is because nothing is listening locally for dns requests over ipv6, see this github thread: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/12159